# Deleting Node entry in the Sensu Client List Remotely

Tags: sensu

I am using Terraform to Auto Provision and Puppet to push the applications. I have integrated a sensu server to monitor the server activity. This whole process is automated through Jenkins. After decommissioning the server, the node entry is still present in the Sensu client list.

`sensu-cli client delete <node_name>`

I need to use this command inside a bash from the Jenkins server.
Is it possible?

Or is there any way that I can delete the node entry from a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sensu api call to delete the sensu client.

["clientsclient-delete"](https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.26/api/clients-api.html#clientsclient-delete)